# CRM 2011 Plugin development best practice

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am inheriting a set of plugins that appear to be developed by different people.  Some of them follow the pattern of one master plugin with many different steps.  In this plugin none of the steps are cohesive or related in functionality, the author simply put them all in the same plugin with code internal to the plugin (if/else madness) that handles the various different entities, crm messages (update, create, delete, etc..) and stages (preValidation/post operation etc.).

The other developer seems to make a plugin for every entity type and/or related feature grouping.  This results in multiple smaller plugins with fewer steps.

My question is this, assuming I have architected a way out of the if/else hell that the previous developer created in the 'one-plugin-to-rule-them-all' design, which approach is preferable from a CRM performance and long term maintenance (as in fewer side effects and difficulties with deployment, etc.) perspective?

Comment: Not much of a question: You already named every single downside of the-one-plugin-to-rule-them-all. From my experience a fine grained control over Pipeline Stage, Step Attributes and Post/Pre-Images yields better maintainability and performance.

Comment: Since that level of control is done when you configure a plugin-step, you don't lose any configurability with the one-plugin-to-rule them all.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have figured out a way to architecturally remove the if/else hell so even that is not an issue.  My question is largely the last sentence.  Does having everything processed in one plugin have any consequences that a new plugin developer may not be aware of.  The processing and entity interactions within CRM can be quite complex, I'm looking for feedback on whether or not I should spend the time breaking up the big plugin, or whether I should merge the smaller ones into the bigger one.  If this is 'not much of a question', then let others handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually follow a **model driven approach** and design one plugin class per entity. On this class steps can be registered for the pre-validation, pre- and post-operation and asynchronous stages on the Create, Update, Delete and other messages, but always for only one entity at a time.

Doing so I can keep a clear oversight of the plugin logic that is triggered on an entity's events and also I do not need to bother about the order in which plugin steps are triggered.

Following this approach, of course, means I need a generic pattern for handling all supported events. For this purpose I designed a plugin base class responsible for the event routing. My deriving plugin classes only need to implement (override) the event handler methods (PreUpdate, PostCreate etc.).

Im my opinion plugin classes should only be used to *glue* system events to the business logic. Therefore the code performing the desired actions should be placed in separate classes. Plugin classes only route the events, prepare the data and call the business logic.

Some developers tend to design one plugin class per step or even per implemented requirement. Doing so keeps your plugin classes terse (which is positive), but when logic gets complicated you can easily loose track of what is going on for a single entity. (Recently I worked with a CRM implementation that had an entity having 21 plugin classes registered for it. Understanding what was going on and adding new behaviour to this entity proved to be very tricky and time consuming.)

Comment: Thank you, this overview was very helpful.  Not being a CRM developer and inheriting a project makes it difficult to judge how best to refactor (or not) the existing code to make future extension and maintenance manageable .  I was fairly certain that the mixed entity, copy paste, 800+ lines in-the-execute-method approach was not a good way to go.

Comment: I often use a similar approach and keeps the plugins in one assembly, however there are times when it's better to split them to different classes and/or assemblies